# I have two <nav> tags rendering in the DOM. How can I change the order just using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two  tags on a page. I want the bottom one to appear before the top one.

I am using the code below. But it is not working.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#main-navigation" ).before( "nav.std-menu" );
});
```

Comment: do you mean get the bottom one first in jquery or actually display it first on the page?

Comment: Display it first on the page: <nav id="main-navigation"> appears after <nav class="std-menu">.  I want to have it appear before. I used .insertBefore but #main-navigation just showed up twice on the page.

Comment: are you appending these `nav` elements with jquery or they are already on the document?

Comment: They are already there. Just looking to rearrange.

Comment: I've already upvoted the correct answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55894099/9172668)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you are trying to do. You can just [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) the `std-menu` navigation element and then insert it in front of `main-navigation` using [insertBefore](https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).

```js
$('#std-menu').detach().insertBefore('#main-navigation');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="main-navigation">Main Navigation</nav>
<nav id="std-menu">Standard Menu</nav>
```

Comment: I meant to say that I wanted to do the opposite of this. But your code was exactly right.  This worked:          $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#main-navigation').detach().insertBefore('nav.std-menu');
        });

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

- detach: https://api.jquery.com/detach/
- insertBefore: http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Comment: Detach kills it all together.  insertBefore renders it twice. If I use them in the same statement insertBefore doesnt pull it back.